# Jenkins email-ext plugin, pre-send scripts:

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

We use `Jenkins` as our ci server, and we run integration test on firefox on `xvfb`. Sometime, we receive the email about test failure, caused by `xvfb` starting failed.

So we want to ignore sending email by this case. As we know, the `email-ext` plugin can help us. we should write `pre-send scripts`, but we don't know how to write them.

How do I write a script to cancel sending email when failure output message contains a specified error message?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967191/jenkins-email-ext-pre-send-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `groovy script` in email-ext plugin pre-send-script is:

```
try {
    def logFilePath = build.getLogFile().getPath();
    String logContent = new File(logFilePath).text;
    if (logContent.find(/Xvfb failed to start/)) cancel=true;
} catch (all) {
}
```

That resolve my problem.